# Respuesta, table.getColumnModel() y getColumn() y setMaxWidth();

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Alguien me podría explicar por favor, como actúa esta línea de código tengo muchas dudas y la verdad no encontré alguna fuente que me ayude acerca de los métodos.

----> table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(35);

- table.getColumnModel()
- getColumn()
- setMaxWidth()

Y si hay alguna fuente que me sirva para entenderlo, estaría muy agradecido :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Establece el ancho máximo de la primer columna de la tabla en 35. Desconozco en que unidad de medida lo hace.

Siendo **table** un objeto de tipo JTable, el método [getColumnModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel()) obtiene un objeto de tipo **TableColumnModel**. Luego [getColumn(0)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#getColumn(int)) obtiene un objeto de tipo **TableColumn** que representa la primer columna definida en el objeto **TableColumnModel** obtenido anteriormente. Por último, el método **setMaxWidth(35)** establece el ancho máximo de esa columna.

El código es lo mismo que escribir:

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn columna = columnModel.getColumn(0);
columna.setMaxWidth(35);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, :D lo máximo